# How to give desktop internet to wireless modem

Tags: networking, router, internet, wireless-router, switch

I just bought K-PIX broadband connection. I have a desktop computer, a wireless modem with 4 LAN port (450TC1 model) and a LAN cable. I also have a wireless USB dongle.

My modem does not have RJ45 port. It has DSL port (I think RJ11, not sure). So I can not connect my broadband cable, which is RJ45, directly to router.

I would like to give/route my internet connection to modem so that I can use wireless capability of modem to my cell phone.

Can someone give any suggestion how to do it? Or its not possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is quite vague, I believe you are saying you have a Beetel 450TC1 ADSL Modem/Router and have switched from ADSL service to a broadband service that gives you a standard Ethernet connection for Internet access?

You should get a different router, one that is a real wireless router and not a ADSL Modem/Router combination. ADSL Modem/Routers in general have no provisions for external Internet access, such as from your new broadband connection, it expects the only Internet access to come from the ADSL connection (which you no longer have). It is likely not possible to make it work as a "standard" WiFi router, especially given it doesn't have the correct interface.

Your best course of action would be to acquire a standard wireless router. Given that you do have a USB dongle, and I assume your computer has a wired Ethernet connection, it is possible you would use Internet Connection sharing (Hotspot), but that would depend on your operating system and setting it up is outside of the scope of these answer, but there are multiple tutorials online for most operating systems that are capable of it.

Comment: Yes. you understood my question correctly. Okay I understood that this router will not help me but as you said I could use hotspot. Could you please explain bit more. I think you are close to answer me. I am using windows 8.1 and yes I have wired ethernet connection.

Comment: For me to instruct you is beyond the scope of the question, you can easily obtain tutorials on the Internet, there are numerous web pages and Youtube videos showing how to do it. You could start here: http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-turn-your-windows-81-laptop-wifi-access-point